# Multiple db accesses or just once access

Tags: mongodb, express, axios, mern

I'm working on an e-commerce website using the MERN stack, I'm about to start retrieving data from the db so I came with this question:
what is the best way to deal with dbs? do I have to keep fetching data each time the user switches from a category to another or just do it once and use it everywhere ?

I tried both but I would like to know others opinions.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on how you implement your e-commerce application.

If you are creating multiple pages of categories then on each page you would do a request. If its a single page application then you would need to get all of your information so that you can display it all when the user goes to that page. If that single page application has a really long page with lots of documents, then you could implement something like pagination or infinite scroll where you would call for more documents as needed.

It's really about how you set up your application. You most likely will make new calls when going to new pages, or one call on a single page with few documents. CRUD - create, read, update, destroy, will all need their own routes as well, which you will obviously call when needed. Although, those don't always have to be implemented on the frontend if you plan to maintain your application from the backend then you can of course tap into MongoDB through the shell.